# Change the time zone on logs on Mailgun

Tags: mailgun

I tried to change the time zone on logs by changing the time zone on account settings but it was not applied. How can I change time zone on logs?

Answer (score 2):

If it doesnt change, maybe you can add your date with the o:deliverytime date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime($yourdate)) on each sent email. https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending

Comment: Have you changed the Timestamp format too? I have te next Config: 
Timezone: Europe/Madrid 
Timestamp Format: 14.04.2016 13:11

Also if you had changed config and you haven´t logged out yet, you can try to log out and log in to see if config is applied.